# Verilog assigning wire by iterating over array

Tags: verilog

How to assign a wire with a AND operation of a wire array?

```
    parameter row = 4;
    parameter col = 8;
    wire ready [row-1:0][col-1:0];
    output wire allready;
```

logically i want to do

allready=AND ready[i][j] for all i,j

Comment: This is a cross-posted question also on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25103242/97073).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a mutlibit wire the reduction operator `&` can be used:

```
wire [row-1:0] ready;
wire allready = &ready;
```

However this will not work with unpacked arrays (multi-dimensions).

One solution is to create a loop to index the dimensions ANDing the values with the result so far. This could be achieved with some thing along the lines of:

```
output reg allready; 

always @* begin
  allready=1'b1;
  for (int i =0; i<col; i++) begin
    allready = allready & (&ready[i]) ;
  end 
end
```

Comment: is the for loop time consuming? or is it the same as ANDing all the wires and assignning the result in a new wire?

Comment: Each loop will take some time for the simulator, but it is unrolled in hardware, ie it is all in parallel. Loops can not consume time other wise they are not synthesizable.